# How to share a child object of a Master-Detail relationship in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

My data model is as follows: Contact(Master) -> CustomObject (Detail). I want to share the CustomObject only with another person and send them an email stating that they have access.

I have tried to create a Share object on the CustomObject, but the Share object does not exist. Digging through documentation has revealed that you cannot use Apex Managed sharing to share a detail/child object, and I cannot share it using Sharing rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
Master-detail is all or nothing. You can see an order header - it makes sense to see all order lines. You'll have to rethink your sharing model.

When something becomes a detail:

- OwnerId field disappears
- Sharing rules for this object disappear
- Forget about any "My [objects]" and "My team's [objects]" in reports, list views
- you can't target it in approval rules

If this is unacceptable - switch back to lookup to contact and achieve what m-d gives you by other means (handmade rollup summaries, cascade delete...)

Comment: Thank you. My solution required me to work around the master-detail relationship altogether and I ended up not needing to share the records at all. For anyone looking at this, you cannot share detail records.